# pandas - ignore rows or columns filled of 0

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm working with pandas dataframe (containing only integers) of various sizes, which regurlarly have lines and columns full of 0, for example :

```
        A   B   C   D   E   F   G
line1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
line2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
line3   0   0   0   1   2   3   4
line4   0   0   0   0   1   2   3
line5   0   0   0   0   0   1   2
```

I want to exclude the lines or columns which are only containing 0, in order to have :

```
        D   E   F   G
line3   1   2   3   4
line4   0   1   2   3
line5   0   0   1   2
```

I think I could select those cells by asserting the sum of each lines and column, for instance (there are probably other ways to do I suppose), but since I'm a newbie to pandas I'm getting a bit confused. How can I do that ?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`any()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) slicer specifying `axis=1` for columns and `axis=0` for rows:

```
df.loc[(df != 0).any(axis=1),(df != 0).any(axis=0)]
```

Comment: works perfectly, thanks ! I'll dive more into pandas tutorials now.

Comment: @Wen thanks, did not initially notice that rows need to be filtered as well, I still like your version better!

Comment: Nope, yours is better base on the speed  , ne and eq always slow that the simple = and != : -)

Answer (score 3):

```
df.loc[df.ne(0).any(1),df.ne(0).any()]
Out[168]: 
       D  E  F  G
line3  1  2  3  4
line4  0  1  2  3
line5  0  0  1  2
```

Comment: @Micawber yw~:-)